# How to fetch data from a website in android app after entering his personal details during registration?

Tags: android, json, web-services, web-applications, jsoup

I want to build an android app that takes users personal information like age, sex, Income etc and also their preferences like Tax,scholarship, bank etc during registration. 
The app will then use this data to fetch relevant information from Indian government websites and display it to the user more like flipboard.
How do I do this?

Thank You.

Comment: Too broad question, check how you ask in Stackoverflow.

Comment: May be the answer is: please open your IDE and start develop App, plz do not forget database :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a RESTful web service on your server which takes the arguments like (age,income,etc) and store these arguments to a new variable then use those variable when connecting the government's website. After that you can use your government's APIs if there are any, if not: you can write a web scraper for that particular website.

You can check this tutorial for web scraping with Node JS:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/scraping-the-web-with-node-js

Comment: Thank you! I'll try out your method.